# Plot circle of radio `r` in complex plane

Tags: plotting, complex, table

I am having a brain-not-working day...

Embarrassingly, I can't figure out how to plot a circle on the complex plane with origin `z_0` and radio `r`. Do I just pretend I'm in `R^2`? Not ideal, since I'd also like to be able to create a table of coordinate points from the circle, too.

Sorry to ask such a basic question. I've got flu and I'm trying to keep myself entertained...

Comment: Please look under `Applications` for `ComplexListPlot`. Get well soon.

Comment: I think the simples is to treat the imaginary axes like an real y axis and then use ` r = 1; z0 = {1, 1}; ParametricPlot[z0 + r ({1, 0} Sin[phi] + {0, 1} Cos[phi]), {phi, 0, 2 Pi}] `

Comment: I don't think this is a well-formed question. Are you really asking for convenient ways to map back-and-forth between the complex plane and the "regular" cartesian plane? In one direction you have `ReIm` (as well as `Abs` and `Arg`). In the other you can just apply `Complex`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
z0 = 1 + I;
r = 2;
plot1 = ParametricPlot[ReIm[z0 + r E^(I \[Theta])], {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi]}]
```

[image]

```
points = 
 Table[z0 + r E^(I \[Theta]), {\[Theta], 0, 2 \[Pi], \[Pi]/12}]
```

[image]

```
plot2 = ListPlot[ReIm[points]];
Show[plot1, plot2]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
With[{z0 = 1 + 2 I, r = 3}, 
 ComplexContourPlot[
  Abs[z - z0] == r, {z, z0 - r (1 + I), z0 + r (1 + I)}]]
```

[image]

```
With[{z0 = 1 + 2 I, r = 3}, 
 ComplexContourPlot[
  Abs[z - z0] == r, {z, z0 - r (1 + I), z0 + r (1 + I)}, 
  MeshFunctions -> {Abs[# - z0] &, Arg[# - z0] &}, Mesh -> {{r}, 20}, 
  MeshStyle -> Directive[Red, AbsolutePointSize[8]]]]
```

[image]